# protected method that takes an abstract super class instance and the "access to protected method not permitted" error

Tags: scala, protected

I contrived a fairly trivial example to illustrate my point as follows:

```
abstract class AbstractSuperClass {
  protected def someFunction(num: Int): Int
  def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int
}

class SubclassSquare extends AbstractSuperClass {
  override protected def someFunction(num: Int): Int = num * num
  override def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int =
    someFunction(num) + another.someFunction(num)
}
```

I received the following error message upon execution of the code. (of course, the `main` function is properly defined.)

> Error:(12, 33) method someFunction in class AbstractSuperClass cannot be accessed in AbstractSuperClass
>    Access to protected method someFunction not permitted because
>    prefix type AbstractSuperClass does not conform to
>    class Subclass where the access takes place
>       someFunction(num) + another.someFunction(num)

The method `addition` is causing the problem. The code tries to access the protected field of an `AbstractSuperClass` instance, but from my perspective, it should cause no issue here since the `SubclassSquare` is a sub-class of `AbstractSuperClass`.

However, I know there must be something I do not understand here. I would like to know how to change my code to make it compile. Well-appreciated.

Comment: It seems you can not access a `protected` field on another instance. However, that seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, normally you would be able to access the protected field of another object so long as both are instances of the same class. Technically, the parameter `another` and `this` are both instances of AbstractSuperClass, so one would think that it works, but it apparently does not.

Comment: Plus one for the opening volley, or if you prefer, sally. I hope they add a template for the bug tracker that begins: "I contrived a fairly trivial example to illustrate my point as follows."

Answer (score 5):

In scala, protected is more restrictive  than in java.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910303/3287419) very helpful while understanding protected modifier for scala.

> if protected member is not qualified(i.e. its just plain protected)
>   then it is visible with another instances of declaring class into
>   declaring class as well as with `this` into class and subclass.

So you could modify your addition function in `SubclassSquare` as follows:

```
override def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int =
      someFunction(num) + another.asInstanceOf[SubclassSquare].someFunction(num)
```

This code would compile, but it’d crash if the argument is not an instance of `SubclassSquare`, so it’s not a good solution.

The better way is to use **access qualifiers**. So you just need to specify your package name with protected modifier  e.g. `protected[yourPackageName]`. Doing this will make your protected member accessible in classes in declared package or below. So your code will look like:

```
abstract class AbstractSuperClass {
    protected[yourPackageName] def someFunction(num: Int): Int
    def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int
  }

  class SubclassSquare extends AbstractSuperClass {
    override protected[yourPackageName] def someFunction(num: Int): Int = num * num
    override def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int =
      someFunction(num) + another.someFunction(num)
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can widen the access:

```
package prot

abstract class AbstractSuperClass {
  protected[prot] def someFunction(num: Int): Int
  def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int
}

class SubclassSquare extends AbstractSuperClass {
  override protected[prot] def someFunction(num: Int): Int = num * num
  override def addition(another: AbstractSuperClass, num: Int): Int = someFunction(num) + another.someFunction(num)
}
```

The spec words:

> A protected identifier x may be used as a member name in a selection
>   r.x
>
> only if one of the following applies:
>
> The access is within the template defining the member, or, if a qualification C
>   is given, inside the package C, or the class C, or its companion
>   module, or
>
> r is one of the reserved words this and super,
>
> or r 's type conforms to a type-instance of the class which contains the access.

So access depends on what you're selecting from.

You fell afoul of the third condition, and the first is the remedy.